# Firestore Internal Assertion Error on calling firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a reactJS app using create-react-app and firestore.

When I try to get a server timestamp when adding a document to firestore by calling

```
await firebase.firestore()
      .collection('messages')
      .add({ timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });
```

I get the following error at seemingly random times. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. The document doesn't end up being written to firestore.

```
index.cjs.js:175 Uncaught Error: FIRESTORE (5.8.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: 
AsyncQueue is already failed: Error: FIRESTORE (5.8.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unknown FieldValue {"localWriteTime":{"seconds":1548602883,"nanoseconds":762000000},"previousValue":null,"typeOrder":3}
at fail (index.cjs.js:175) at JsonProtoSerializer.toValue (index.cjs.js:6976) at index.cjs.js:7726 at Array.map () 
at JsonProtoSerializer.toCursor (index.cjs.js:7725) 
at JsonProtoSerializer.toQueryTarget (index.cjs.js:7558) 
at JsonProtoSerializer.toTarget (index.cjs.js:7650) 
at PersistentListenStream.watch (index.cjs.js:16906) 
at RemoteStore.sendWatchRequest (index.cjs.js:17859) 
at RemoteStore.listen (index.cjs.js:17814) at SyncEngine. (index.cjs.js:19354) 
at step (tslib.es6.js:197) 
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:127) 
at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:80) 
at fail (index.cjs.js:175) 
at AsyncQueue.verifyNotFailed (index.cjs.js:8735) 
at AsyncQueue.enqueue (index.cjs.js:8682) 
at AsyncQueue.enqueueAndForget (index.cjs.js:8671) 
at index.cjs.js:16850 
at StreamBridge.wrappedOnMessage (index.cjs.js:16801) 
at StreamBridge.callOnMessage (index.cjs.js:7992) 
at index.cjs.js:8267 
at W. (index.cjs.js:8210) 
at W.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.Lb (index.esm.js:860) 
at W.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.dispatchEvent (index.esm.js:815) 
at X.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.X.ud (index.esm.js:3682) 
at $c.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.dg (index.esm.js:3431) at $c.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.ue (index.esm.js:3320) 
at R.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.Yc (index.esm.js:1875) 
at R.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.Fd (index.esm.js:1771) 
at R.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.hg (index.esm.js:1733) 
at R.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.Me (index.esm.js:1690) 
at R.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.mg (index.esm.js:1685) 
at V.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.Lb (index.esm.js:860) 
at V.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.dispatchEvent (index.esm.js:815) 
at V.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.se (index.esm.js:2840) at V.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.eg (index.esm.js:2836) 
at V.push../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/dist/index.esm.js.e.te (index.esm.js:2832)
```

I've found [this thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1073) on the firebase github which claims to have solved the issue however after upgrading to firebase SDK 5.8.0 and firebase tools 6.3.0 the error still persists.

Has anyone else had this error or does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!